# Git workflow: IP work in branch

Tags: git

Here's the workflow I'm coming up against.  How would you solve this in git?

I'm working on a feature in a branch, committing when it's appropriate.  I'm in the middle of some exploratory work, stuff that I **don't** want to commit, because there's a good chance I'm going to throw it out anyway.

I need to drop what I'm doing and go work on another branch.  I'm sure you'd like to suggest `git stash`.  I use it all the time for temporary switching, but I plan on leaving my work in this exploratory branch for a week or more.  I've found `git stash` to be unwieldy when they start to stack up and you're trying to make sense of what's what - a situation that's sure to happen if that's how I proceed.

If the index were branch-specific, that would be great I would just leave this stuff in the index in this branch.  If `git stash` were branch-specific, that would be great I could just leave one stash pushed on to this branch.  And my stashes in other branches wouldn't bury this one.

Why not just make a new commit?  I feel that's subverting the meaning of a commit, when this is unfinished work.  I don't want this in the commit history if it turns out I trash it all.

Using a more conventional vcs, I would just re-checkout from another location on my file system, leaving my current work untouched.

What's the git way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can commit it on the branch, and then expunge it later with `git rebase -i` if you don't want it.

Or, just create a temporary branch based off your current branch, and commit it there. Then delete the temporary branch if you don't want it.

Comment: I see, time to put `rebase` in the toolbox.  If I create a temporary branch won't that show up as a commit if I keep it and merge it back?  I guess `rebase` can do the squashing magic to pretend like that commit never happened?

Comment: If commit your experiment on a temporary branch, and decide you want to keep it, then yes, it will show up as a commit on the temporary branch *and* a merge commit when you bring it back onto your main feature branch. The exception to this is if there are no other commits on the feature branch in the meantime, in which case the default merge behaviour is a fast-forward merge which results in your experiment appearing directly in the main branch's history with no record of the temporary branch.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a more conventional vcs, I would just re-checkout from another location on my file system, leaving my current work untouched.

You can do that, using `git clone`. I don't particularly like having two clones on the same machine, as a standard way of keeping two separate lines of development. But I think it makes sense for your use case.